# IBOutlet works in iOS 6 but null in iOS 4.3?

Tags: ios, interface-builder

I have a custom view for my tableview's header

```
UIView *headerTableview_;    
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIView *headerTableview;
```

I have connected it to xib file.

Then in .m file,

```
@synthesize headerTableview = headerTableview_;

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{
  return headerTableview_.frame.size.height;
}

- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{
  return headerTableview_;
}
```

Then, I try to run it, in iOS 6 it's displayed well, but in iOS 4.3, it's not displayed at all.

What could be the problem? Anyone knows how to fix this weird problem?
Thanks!

Comment: Do both methods run when setting a breakpoint?

Comment: oops sorry..yes..but in iOS 4 when I try to NSLog headerTableview_, it returns null

Comment: What kind of views do you have in headerTableview? maybe your using some view class not available in iOS 4.3, but then you should probably have seen some error log.

Comment: Doesn't it work when you just remove the first line with `UIView *headerTableview_;` in the .h file?

Comment: It shouldn't even build with the UIView *headerTableview_; in the .h within the @interface. You are synthesizing to the _ in your .m.

Comment: hmm but please note it works for ios 6 but not in ios 4.3, so it shouldn't be the problems.. btw, I use a UIView.. That's why this problem is very weird

Comment: Yes, but >iOS4.3 may remedy the issue (error correction). It sounds like the view isn't initializing properly so you may be better of creating a subclass of UIView and using that instead that way you can assign its frame in its init method.

Comment: so i think it's better to do it programmatically?

Comment: No, you shouldn't need to do this programmatically but you may just need to create a new class for your UIView so you can handle any init methods directly and not rely on IB to do this for you. At least this way you can place a breakpoint on the class itself and check it's attributes before it's returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your .h file

```
@interface testViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
{

UITableView *tableView;
}
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *testView;
@end
```

In your .m file

```
@implementation testViewController

@synthesize testView;
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

tableView = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:self.view.frame style:UITableViewStylePlain];
tableView.delegate = self;
tableView.dataSource =self;
[self.view addSubview:tableView];
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:tableView];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{
return testView.frame.size.height;
}

- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{
return testView;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
return 2;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
return 3;

}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Products";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];}
//UIImage *currentTweet = [[xmlParser tweets] objectAtIndex:1];
cell.textLabel.text= @"text label";
cell.detailTextLabel.text=@"detailTextLabel";

return cell;}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void)dealloc {
[testView release];
[super dealloc];
}
@end
```

[image: Attaching image of o/p from simulator iOS4.3.2]

Comment: @ I've run it on simulator I'm attaching screen shot check my EDIT. The one in grey color is the 'test view' that I added.

Comment: is it @synthesize _testView = testView; ? because I got compile error for _testView

Comment: I only tested using @syntesize testView;

Comment: Generally you should synthesize as such. @synthesize headerTableview = _headerTableview; This is for memory management reasons (self.)

Comment: hey dude! i'm ending on using UIViewController instead of UITableViewController and it works now!

Answer (score 0):

Create a new class file named HeaderTableview. See if this initializes properly when assigning in IB.

```
//.h
@class HeaderTableview;

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet HeaderTableview *headerTableview;

//.m
@synthesize headerTableview = _headerTableview;

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return _headerTableview.frame.size.height;
}
```

Comment: yeah this one is right... it seems the IBOUtlet doesn't initialize my view